# Transferring data to another table using SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

If in the process of moving my prodiuct categories out of the main table into seperate tables. At the moment its stored like this:

```
ProductId       Product Name        Cat1    Cat2    Cat3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1           Something One              Y        N       N
2           Another                    N        Y       N
3           Product Three              Y        N       Y
4           Final One                  N        N       Y
```

My new tables look like this:

```
CatID   CatName
---------------------------
1       Cat1
2       Cat2
3       Cat3

ID  CatID   ProductID
-----------------------------------
1   1       1
2   2       2
3   1       1
4   1       3
5   3       4
```

My question is; is it possible to transfer this information from the main table to the new table using SQL? I have over 500 products and don't fancy doing it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.. assuming the new table has an autonumber on ID

```
insert into CatProduct(CatID, ProductID)
select 1, ProductID
from Product
where Cat1 = 'Y'
union all
select 2, ProductID
from Product
where Cat2 = 'Y'
union all
select 3, ProductID
from Product
where Cat3 = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, assuming your tables are Category, Product and CategoryXProduct (with ID definned as identity):

```
INSERT CategoryXProduct ( CatID, ProductID ) 
    SELECT 1, ProductId FROM Product WHERE Cat1 = 'Y'
INSERT CategoryXProduct ( CatID, ProductID ) 
    SELECT 2, ProductId FROM Product WHERE Cat2 = 'Y'
INSERT CategoryXProduct ( CatID, ProductID ) 
    SELECT 3, ProductId FROM Product WHERE Cat3 = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you may be able to do this sort of transformation using MySQL queries directly, why not just use an external scripting language to handle it?  PHP, Python, etc. all have MySQL libraries.

Comment: @Cyberkiwi: "Squatting"?  Yes, as I said, I'm sure it can be done without leaving the database server.  What I was implying is that the alternative is not "doing it by hand" (as the questioner seems to think).  If this is a one-off transformation, if you can't immediately think of the perfect set of queries, why not just hack together a quick script?

Comment: @cyberwiki: It's an answer to the problem, not necessarily the precise question.  I'm pretty sure that's allowed.  If you think the answer is wrong, inappropriate, or incorrect, then downvote it!

Comment: I could do it in PHP but I thought there might be a much easier way of doing it in SQL

Comment: @Alex: As other answers have shown, in this case, there's an easy way to do it in SQL.  However, all transformations are not necessarily this simple!

Comment: The data does not need to leave MySQL, which involves all sorts of inefficiencies like network i/o, double transfer (in/out) etc. Best done using SQL on the server itself

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. there is sth like INSERT from SELECT:

```
INSERT into table1(id, name, fname)
SELECT id, lname, fname
FROM authors
WHERE somecondiction
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your product-category relationship many-to-one (as I can see from the example rows given)? Then you may also consider adding the product's category id as a column in the products table instead of creating the join table to avoid the join with this table in queries.